# Nordic PCA 10040 nRF52 DK communication with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, nrf52

currently, I am working on an app for my masterthesis. This application should communicate with the Nordic PCA 10040 nRF52 DK. Therefor I have downloaded the example folder of nordic and used the peripherals example with uart. Unfortunately, I always get an error when I try to use the RX-Characteristic which has the UUID: 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e. The examples code uses an other UUID which is 0x0002. Obviously, it is a part of the mentioned UUID but where is the rest of it? I mean I could imagine that this is a kind of format which reduces data and the rest of the UUID will be added in an algorithm but I couldn´t find it. The C-Code is really big and I have searched for hours. Do you think this is the issue? I have read that there is a bug in the code but I am not sure if that is true.

Kind Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Have you tried to use the characteristic using [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Android? Add more detail; is your nordic device configured as a periphereal and the android app is central? Which side do you have the issue in?

Comment: It is an android application this is why I added this tag. Yes, you are right. My application is the central and the nordic is the peripheral. The issue is on the central side. I want to send a message to me peripheral but always when I use the Rx characteristic UUID of the peripheral my app crashes. I get a Null Pointer Exception. It seems like the UUID does not exist but it is exactly the uuid from their webside.

Comment: Did you try BLE app uart example from the nrf SDK? What happens when you flash BLE app uart example, use nRF connect app and send data from that particular characteristics?

Comment: actually I have solved my issue. It was ridiculous...I just cleared the ble cache and it worked...I have spent hours to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, I have solved my issue. I am not sure if it was the best solution but I simply cleared my "ble cache" and it worked. If you have the same issue you can try this, too, but I cannot guarantee that it will solve your problem.

Kind Regards,
Thomas